# Get case class field's name and type with shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is it possible to get scala case class field's names and types with shapeless?

I've tried like this (T is case class):

```
trait Cpo[T] {

def withPrimaryKey[R <: HList, K, V <: HList](f: Seq[Symbol] => Seq[Symbol])(
    implicit labellGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R], keys: Keys.Aux[R, K],
    ktl: hlist.ToList[K, Symbol]): Cpo[T]
}
```

but I only can get field's name.

Zlaja

Comment: Is it necessary to use shapeless ? Asking because you can easily do it with Product class

Comment: @Shantiswarup, any example?

Comment: I have added the sample code as answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
object typeablePoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A](implicit typeable: Typeable[A]): Case.Aux[A, String] = at(_ => typeable.describe)
}

trait Cpo[T] {

  def withPrimaryKey[R <: HList, K <: HList, V <: HList, V1 <: HList](f: Seq[Symbol] => Seq[Symbol])(implicit
    labellGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
    keys: Keys.Aux[R, K],
    ktl: hlist.ToList[K, Symbol],
    values: Values.Aux[R, V],
    mapper: hlist.Mapper.Aux[typeablePoly.type, V, V1],
    vtl: hlist.ToList[V1, String]
  ): Cpo[T] 
}
```

Now `ktl` gives list of field names (as `Symbol`s) and `vtl` gives list of field types (as `String`s).

---

Try

```
  object typeablePoly extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[A](implicit typeable: Typeable[A]): Case.Aux[A, String] = at(_ => typeable.describe)
  }

  object nullPoly extends Poly0 {
    implicit def default[A]: ProductCase.Aux[HNil, A] = at(null.asInstanceOf[A])
  }

  trait Cpo[T] {

    def withPrimaryKey[R <: HList, K <: HList, V <: HList, V1 <: HList](f: Seq[Symbol] => Seq[Symbol])(implicit
      labellGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
      keys: Keys.Aux[R, K],
      ktl: hlist.ToList[K, Symbol],
      values: Values.Aux[R, V],
      mapper: hlist.Mapper.Aux[typeablePoly.type, V, V1],
      fillWith: hlist.FillWith[nullPoly.type, V],
      vtl: hlist.ToList[V1, String]
    ): Cpo[T] = {
      println(ktl(keys())) // List('i, 's)
      println(vtl(mapper(fillWith()))) // List(Int, String)
      ???
    }
  }

  case class MyClass(i: Int, s: String)
  new Cpo[MyClass] {}.withPrimaryKey(identity)
```

Comment: If I figured out correctly, to get fields types I need to have instance of T? Is it possible to get fields types just using type T?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can get field names. For example, here you can find how to write your shapeless-based generic derivation mechanism: [Bits of shapeless part 2](http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-2/.). 
More specific, you should look at **Deriving case Classes** part, there is a function which derives encoder for arbitrary case class, its signature is:

```
implicit def hconsToJson[Key <: Symbol, Head, Tail <: HList](
    implicit key: Witness.Aux[Key],
    headWrites: JsonWrites[Head],
    tailWrites: JsonWrites[Tail])
    : JsonWrites[FieldType[Key, Head] :: Tail] = ???
```

Hence, `key` parameter allows you to acces the field name of the certain field.
For the types, the only known way to me is to use reflection. Read this for details [Scala manual on type tags](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

Answer (score 0):

If using shapeless is not necessary, you can get the type as well as value using Product class in scala

```
case class Test(x:Int,y:String,z:Boolean)
println(getGeyNameValueType(Test(1,"a",true)).foreach(println))

def getGeyNameValueType(inp: Product): Iterator[(Any, Class[_])] = {
    val itr = inp.productIterator
    for {
      item <- itr
    } yield (item, item.getClass)
}
```

The output is

```
(1,class java.lang.Integer)
(a,class java.lang.String)
(true,class java.lang.Boolean)
()
```

Comment: Yes, but it must have instance of T. I want to do that without instance. I made it with shapeless.